# Push a value to a Global array in a recursive loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I'm a bit new to JavaScript. How can I push a new value to the array routes. It seems for some reason the push function is being called after the recursion has ended.

I know I have to use call back closures but having a problem implementing them and have the value of routes reflect correctly

Below are the outputs I want pushed to my routes array

```
[0,1,3,4]
[0,2,4]
[0,3,4]
```

instead I get

```
[[0],[0],[0]]
```

Please assist below is the code I've commented the area the bug is coming from.

````
var popMap;
var routes = [];

function removeA(arr) {
  var what, a = arguments, L = a.length, ax;
  while (L > 1 && arr.length) {
      what = a[--L];
      while ((ax= arr.indexOf(what)) !== -1) {
          arr.splice(ax, 1);
      }
  }
  return arr;
}


const initPopMap = (numPops) => {
  popMap = Array(numPops);
  for(var i = 0; i < numPops; i++ ){
    popMap[i] = [];
  }
}


const addEdge = (origin, destination) => {
  popMap[origin].push(destination);
} 

const getRoutes = (origin,destination,visitedPops,routePath) => {
  visitedPops[origin] = true;

  if(origin == destination){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(routePath))
////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////
////BUG IS HERE//////////////////////

    routes.push(routePath);

///////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////
    visitedPops[origin] = false;
    return;
  }

  for (let index = 0; index < popMap[origin].length; index++) {
    const endPop = popMap[origin][index];

    if(visitedPops[endPop] == false){
      //console.log("PAHTLIST preadd " + routePath);

      routePath.push(endPop);
      //console.log("Post add " + endPop);
      //console.log("PAHTLIST postadd " + routePath);
      getRoutes(endPop,destination,visitedPops,routePath);
      //console.log("PAHTLIST prepop " + routePath);
      routePath = removeA(routePath,endPop);
      //console.log("post POp " + endPop);
      //console.log("PAHTLIST postpop " + routePath);

    }
  }
  visitedPops[origin] = false;
}





const routeDiscover = (origin,destination) => {

  var numOfPops = 5;
  var routePath = [];
  var visitedPops = Array(numOfPops); //This array keeps track of visited nodes

  for(var i = 0; i < visitedPops.length; i++){
    visitedPops[i] = false;
  }
  initPopMap(numOfPops);
  addEdge(0,1); 
  addEdge(0,2); 
  addEdge(0,3); 
  addEdge(1,0); 
  addEdge(1,3); 
  addEdge(2,0);
  addEdge(2,4); 
  addEdge(3,0); 
  addEdge(3,1); 
  addEdge(3,4); 
  addEdge(4,2); 
  addEdge(4,3);



  routePath.push(origin);
  getRoutes(origin,destination,visitedPops,routePath);

  console.log(JSON.stringify(routes));
}



routeDiscover(0,4)```
````

Comment: What is the `a = arguments`? It's not defined anywhere

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the context of this function, so I don't know what `a = arguments` is for. If you replace it with a valid variable, the return will be what you expect.

```js
let popMap;
let routes = [];

const removeA = (arr) => {
  var what, a = [], L = a.length, ax;
  while (L > 1 && arr.length) {
      what = a[--L];
      while ((ax= arr.indexOf(what)) !== -1) {
          arr.splice(ax, 1);
      }
  }
  return arr;
}


const initPopMap = (numPops) => {
  popMap = Array(numPops);
  for(var i = 0; i < numPops; i++ ){
    popMap[i] = [];
  }
}


const addEdge = (origin, destination) => {
  popMap[origin].push(destination);
} 

const getRoutes = (origin,destination,visitedPops,routePath) => {
  visitedPops[origin] = true;

  if(origin == destination){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(routePath))
    routes.push(routePath);
    visitedPops[origin] = false;
    return;
  }

  for (let index = 0; index < popMap[origin].length; index++) {
    const endPop = popMap[origin][index];

    if(visitedPops[endPop] == false){
      //console.log("PAHTLIST preadd " + routePath);

      routePath.push(endPop);
      //console.log("Post add " + endPop);
      //console.log("PAHTLIST postadd " + routePath);
      getRoutes(endPop,destination,visitedPops,routePath);
      //console.log("PAHTLIST prepop " + routePath);
      routePath = removeA(routePath,endPop);
      //console.log("post POp " + endPop);
      //console.log("PAHTLIST postpop " + routePath);

    }
  }
  visitedPops[origin] = false;
}





const routeDiscover = (origin,destination) => {

  var numOfPops = 5;
  var routePath = [];
  var visitedPops = Array(numOfPops); //This array keeps track of visited nodes

  for(var i = 0; i < visitedPops.length; i++){
    visitedPops[i] = false;
  }
  initPopMap(numOfPops);
  addEdge(0,1); 
  addEdge(0,2); 
  addEdge(0,3); 
  addEdge(1,0); 
  addEdge(1,3); 
  addEdge(2,0);
  addEdge(2,4); 
  addEdge(3,0); 
  addEdge(3,1); 
  addEdge(3,4); 
  addEdge(4,2); 
  addEdge(4,3);



  routePath.push(origin);
  getRoutes(origin,destination,visitedPops,routePath);

  console.log(JSON.stringify(routes));
}



routeDiscover(0,4);
```